# VirtualBox Ubuntu Share Guest VPN with Host

Tags: virtualbox, vpn

I need to connect to my work VPN, but my work uses juniper network-connect. I have a 64 bit Ubuntu running 14.04, but not a single one of the juniper tutorials have worked for me (I've been at this for close to a month). However, I have had success connecting to my work VPN by setting up a virtual-box guest with 32 bit lubuntu.

Now that I have my guest box correctly connecting to my work VPN, does anyone know how I can route my host traffic through my guest?